# How to setup FedAuth with a unique login page per site?

Tags: federated-authentication

I've setup fedauth in Sitecore 9 for my site which is working as expected for a single site. However I'm having a multisite solution and each site needs it's own login page. The login page is specified in the NoAccessUrl setting, which is set in Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Enabler.config. This is using Sitecore 9 update 1 using wsFed.

Is it possible to have a different NoAccessUrl per site?

Comment: Can you give more information? What Sitecore version? How have you configured the federated authentication? What is doing the authentication? etc... - The more details you can give, the more likely you will be to get an answer.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? The loginpage is used to redirect when someone is not authenticated at all. NoAccess is also used when the user does not have the required role for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try setting the login page from config file? something like :

```
  <sites>
      <site name="Your_Website_Name" set:loginPage="/api/controller/method">
  </site>
```

OR

```
   <sites>
      <site name="Your_Website_Name" set:loginPage="/your presentation item path">
   </site>
```